# .xlsm to csv using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, export-to-csv

I would like to convert several files that are in a folder from .xlsm to csv. The Excel files contain multiple sheets.
Because my knowledge with Powershell is very limited at the moment I searched online for a script and found one at [Extract and convert all Excel worksheets into CSV files using PowerShell](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3223/extract-and-convert-all-excel-worksheets-into-csv-files-using-powershell/)

The problem is that on a few occasions I have managed to make these scripts work (one script calls the other) but I have not figured out when or how it happens.
I'm running the script(s) from Powershell ISE and get the following error message:

> Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Sorry, we couldn't find C:\Docs. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"
>   At C:\Docs\xlstocsv.ps1:9 char:5
>   +     $wb = $E.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

Because I have successfully ran these scripts a couple of times then it is right to assume that the scripts are correct and there is something wrong with my Powershell(?) setup? 
I have run out of ideas.

PS I hope it is allowed here to paste links to other web pages.

EDIT
Code added.

**Script one** (the one I start from Powershell ISE):

```
$ens = Get-ChildItem "C:\Docs\" -filter *.xlsm
foreach($e in $ens)
{   [threading.thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'en-US'
    ExportWSToCSV -excelFileName $e.BaseName -csvLoc "C:\Docs\Final\"
}
```

**Script two**:

```
Function ExportWSToCSV ($excelFileName, $csvLoc)

{   [threading.thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'en-US'
    $excelFile = "C:\Docs\"
    $E = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $E.Visible = $false
    $E.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $wb = $E.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
    foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets)
    {
        $n = $excelFileName + "_" + $ws.Name
        $ws.SaveAs($csvLoc + $n + '.csv', 6)
    }
    $E.Quit()
}
ExportWSToCSV -excelFileName "file" -csvLoc "C:\Docs\Final\"
```

I added the "[threading.thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'en-US'" part and I was able to run these scripts successfully, but only once. So this basically it seems I can discard this line from the code.

Comment: Post *your* code.

Comment: "is right to assume that the scripts are correct and there is something wrong with my Powershell(?) setup?"  No, that would be extremely rare.  It's far more likely there's a bug with your code that is based on how you're handling your files, calling methods, or calling commands.  Your algorithm is correct, but you've assumed that something is always true or never true about your data files, and that assumption is incorrect.  It's not possible to say more without code.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Code added now.

Comment: @BaconBits Make sense. Added the code.

Comment: `$excelFile` is a folder. `$E.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)` tells Excel to try to open that folder as a workbook, which should obviously fail. You probably want to `Join-Path $excelFile $excelFileName` before passing the result of that operation to the `Open()` method.

Comment: Also, what is the point of invoking your function with the basename of a file instead of the complete file name?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thank for pointing this ("$excelFile is a folder") out - if I insert the full path to the xlsm file, then this script creates csv files without problems. But if I want to create a loop to go through all the files in the folder, then I get the error mentioned in my first post. I also modified the scripts (added this line and tried inserting the file name instead of the basename and also added full path to the file that contains that function) but ran into a error: At C:\Docs\xlstocsv3.ps1:5 char:30+ "C:\Docs\xlstocsv.ps1"  -excelFileName $e.BaseName -csvLoc "C:\Docs\Final\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only goal is to convert files from `.xlsm` to `.csv`, you can accomplish this as such (using your example snippets):

```
function Convert-XlsmToCsv {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string] $Path
    )
    begin {
        $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application -Property @{
            Visible       = $false
            DisplayAlerts = $false
        }
    }
    process {
        $root = Split-Path -Path $Path
        $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($Path)
        $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($Path)
        foreach ($worksheet in $workbook.Worksheets) {
            $name = Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath "${filename}_$($worksheet.Name).csv"
            try {
                $worksheet.SaveAs($name, 6)
            } catch {
                Write-Error -Message "Failed to save csv! Path: '$name'. $PSItem"
            }
        }
    }
    end {
        $excel.Quit()
        $null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
    }
}
```

In use:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Docs -Filter *.xlsm |
    Convert-XlsmToCsv
```

This made some assumptions, but it's easy enough to edit.

Comment: I created two .ps1 files based on your code and then ran the file that contained  "Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Docs -Filter *.xlsm | Convert-XlsmToCsv" in Powershell ISE. Unfortunately it returned the following error: "Convert-XlsmToCsv : The term 'Convert-XlsmToCsv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the..." and so on. So I replaced "Convert-XlsmToCsv" with full path to the .ps1 file that contains function, but still could not get it to work... Maybe this script is OK, but I'm just making some rookie mistake...

Comment: The function has to exist in memory before you can call it. Put the code for the function in a file. Lower down in that same file you can write code to call the function. Then execute that file.

Comment: After some research and testing I finally got this working! I saved all this above into one ps1 file and added "    [threading.thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'en-US' " (without double quotation marks) after "begin {". Then I ran it from inside Powershell ISE.